# How to Filter Spcial Character in php

Tags: php, drupal

I am storing records in database by using CCk Content filter (Full HTML type) while i am fetching records displaying like � format  how to rectified ?

�balakrishnan - System � Networking �

how to remove alone that special character 
and display the records
is there is any function

Answer (score 1):

There is a function xmlentities()

Try using the same

Comment: i tried xmlentities but not filtering the special symbols. still coming � ������